# SQL Server: For each record in table 1, find the closest match in table 2

Tags: sql-server, join, cross-apply

I have 2 tables.

**table1**

```
date1, closingprice
```

**table2**

```
 date2, strikeprice, ask
```

For each record in table 1, I want to match on `table1.date1 = table2.date2 - 4` to find `table2.strikeprice` that is the closest to `table1.closingprice` but where `table1.closingprice > table2.strikeprice`

For each record in `table1`, where the date matches on the date in `table2`, there are multiple records in `table2`.  But I am interested in only 1 record in `table2` based on the constraint above.

I want `table2.date2`, `strikeprice`, and ask from `table2` in the output results.

I match on the dates using `table1.date1 = DATEADD(DD, -4, table2.date2)` and that works fine...

Any ideas on how to do this as simple as possible?  Explanations on what is happening would be appreciated.  I have seen an example with `CROSS APPLY`, but open to any example that is easily understood and why it works....

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have any sample data and expected results and can you please show us what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` and use a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select t1.*, t2.strikeprice
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
    on t1.date1 = dateadd(DD, -4, t2.date2)
    and t2.strikeprice = (
        select max(strikeprice)
        from table2 t22
        where t22.date2 = t2.date2
        and t22.strikeprice < t1.closingprice
    )
```

This assumes that there are no duplicates on `table2(date2, strikeprice)`; otherwise, you might get duplicates in the resultset. This assumption seems consistant with your question though.

Comment: Yep.   This is what I wanted....I was able to use this with a few modifications.  Thank you!